# Windows Forms Layout Engines

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

Does anyone have or know best practices for implementing a custom layout engine in WinForms?  I've seen the [windowsclient.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973821.aspx) link, but it's a bit dated (Sept 2001).

Answer (score 4):

When I tried to do custom layout engine in WinForms, I was blocked by the fact that IArrangedElement interface is internal. It looks stupid, but it seems you can't get layout properties in a uniform way unless you develop System.Windows.Forms itself.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not very impressed with the layout capabilities in WinForms.

Answer (score 2):

You can always check out [DevExpress Layout Control](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Layout/). It's not free but it is an eye opener.

Comment: Interesting...I'll play with it and see what I find.